# MPMoviePlayerViewController video not played using URL in ios

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to play video using URL but it's not playing.
Here is my code :-

```
var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: mediaItem.fileURL)
self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(moviePlayer)
moviePlayer?.moviePlayer.play()
```

Not getting any kind of error and also not played .

I also checked URL value.Value pass properly but again not play video.

so any one have solution then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is player open for video ?

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerViewController ` is deprecated use `AVPlayerViewController` instead.

Comment: Did you check app transport security? <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: Hello Tejas,
both security added.

Comment: Hello  ivarun,
i tried below code but not work.
let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()  , var playerView = AVPlayer(), let asset =  AVURLAsset.init(url: mediaItem.fileURL) ,let item =  AVPlayerItem.init(asset: asset) ,playerView = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: item), playerVC.player = playerView, self.present(playerVC, animated: true) playerVC.player?.play()

Comment: Also as per ivarun, MPMoviePlayerViewController you should use AVPlayerViewController

Comment: Please share video url so we can try here

Comment: Hello tejas,
i found issue.My url contains https thats why not play video.so https related any solution then please help me.

Comment: Check your server have valid ssl certificate installed or not.

Comment: But my image also load from same sever and it's working properly.

Comment: @tejas,
i will check tomorrow ssl certificate of server.

Answer (score 2):

```swift
import AVKit

let url = URL(string: "http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov")
let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
{
    playerViewController.player?.play()
}
```

Comment: Hello suresh ,
My issue relate to http and https.so how to load Https url?

Answer (score 1):

As `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is deprecated from iOS 9 use `AVPlayerViewController` instead.

Make sure your video URL is correct because i am able to play video from URL with below code:

```
import AVKit

let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
avPlayerController.player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL.init(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")!)
avPlayerController.player?.play()
present(avPlayerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if your URL is not https then please add below code in plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Hello ivarun, 
My url contain https.so confirmed with network person related to SSL certificate.
Thank You

Comment: i have tried your video URL which is posted in comment but don't know somehow it is now playing. :(

Comment: it looks like video url is not proper. please ask your backend developer. coz video is not even playing in browser.

Comment: are you able to find issue?

Comment: hello ivaru ,
Video available on local server that's why not play in your browser.jab.astppbilling.org it's our local server.

Comment: Still i’m able to download that video but not able to play in browser.